# Laravel 5 - MD5 Hash error gravatar

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm trying to use Gravatar which requires an MD5 hash on the email, when I try this using Laravel and blade it just outputs my code instead of running it.

**Model**

```
public function getAvatarUrl()
{
    return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ md5($this->email) }}?d=mm&s=40";
}
```

**View**

```
<img class="media-object avatar" alt="{{ $status->user->getNameOrUsername() }}" src="{{ $status->user->getAvatarUrl() }}">
```

The out put on the page is such -

```
<img class="media-object avatar" alt="Sam" src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/{{ md5(sam@myemail.co.uk) }}?d=mm&amp;s=50">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use blade syntax like `{{ }}` in a return. Blade syntax is only allowed in blade templates.

Try this in your model:

```
public function getAvatarUrl()
{
    return "https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5($this->email) . "?d=mm&s=40";
}
```

Comment: Aha Yes thankyou that's resolved the issue the email is now hashed!